# How do I pass ESC to stdin?

Tags: linux, shell

How do I pass <kbd>Esc</kbd> to stdin in shell, the <kbd>Esc</kbd> on a keyboard?

I have discovered that `0x1B` or `^[` is the outputted result of <kbd>Esc</kbd> but how can I input <kbd>Esc</kbd>?

Comment: Is that a trick question? Have you tried pressing the ESC key, to see what happens?

Comment: Sorry, I mean programmatically in a shell script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On most keyboards, it can be entered as <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>.

In a shell script, you could do this (which is [part](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html) of the POSIX shell):

```
printf '\033'
```

and in GNU [`echo`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo), you may do

```
echo -e '\e'
```

Piping either to a script makes that the script's standard input ("stdin"):

```
printf '\033' | myscript
```

Answer (score 0):

### Interactive shell

Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd>

Linux/Mac(bash): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>ESC</kbd>

### Scripting

BASH: `echo -e '\033[92mText In Light Green\033[0m'`

Windows CMD: to be done..